# expect response seen in bash debug but I cant get it.

Tags: bash, expect

I am trying to get the information from a keepass database and I can't get past this last step!

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#!/usr/bin/expect

firewall=$1
password="PASSWORD"
echo "connecting to KeepassDB..."

function get_creds {
expect <<- DONE
    set timeout 10
    spawn kpcli
    match_max 100000000
    expect  "kpcli:/>"
    send    "open /media/sf_VM_shared/keepass.kdb\n"
    expect  "password:"
    send    "$password\n"
    expect  ">"
    send    "cd General/Network/Firewalls/SSH\n"
    expect  "SSH>"
    send    "ls\n"
    expect  ">"
DONE

}


credentials=$(get_creds)
echo $credentials
```

When I do a bash -x I can see what I want, it's a long list of information, but without the -x the script is not returning the list to the terminal.

Comment: Why do you have two shebangs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the output when using bash -x because then every command output is printed after they are run (debug mode)

The script does not print because your last line of output from `get_creds` is empty. It should print the last line of output from the method.

When using echo to output your credentials you should use quoutes (") in order to preserve newlines.

Try replacing the last line in your script with this:

```
echo "$credentials"
```

Comment: Wow! 2 days I was scratching my head. Now I may just bang it on the table. :-) 

Thank you.